# Boolean return value from shell function behaving strangely

Tags: linux, shell

I've defined this function (with some debugging printouts):

```
listcontains() {
  for item in $1
  do
    echo $2 = $item ?
    if [ "$2" == "$item" ]; then
      echo YES!
      return 1;
    fi
  done
  echo NO!
  return 0
}
```

And I'm using it like this:

```
list="1 2"
if listcontains "$list" 3; then echo Y; else echo N; fi
```

I'm expecting N, but the result is Y, and the debug output makes it even more strange:

```
3 = 1 ?
3 = 2 ?
NO!
Y
```

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In shell, you use `0` to denote `true` (and some positive number, i.e. `1`, to denote `false`). It's the same notion as for scripts exit values - in unix world, `0` means success.

So to fix, just reverse return values:

```
listcontains() {
  for item in $1
  do
    echo $2 = $item ?
    if [ "$2" == "$item" ]; then
      echo YES!
      return 0;
    fi
  done
  echo NO!
  return 1
}
```

Example:

```
$ list="1 2"
$ if listcontains "$list" 3; then echo Y; else echo N; fi
3 = 1 ?
3 = 2 ?
NO!
N

$ list="1 3"
$ if listcontains "$list" 3; then echo Y; else echo N; fi
3 = 1 ?
3 = 3 ?
YES!
Y
```